# camerasource takepicture is not working

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am trying to capture and save the image from camera using this project https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker

The code to capture image is in face track activity java file

```
final CameraSource.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new CameraSource.ShutterCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onShutter() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onShutter");
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"sd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        CameraSource.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new CameraSource.PictureCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0) {
            Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);

            //save file
            String path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM.toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),path,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(path, "FitnessGirl"+".jpg"); // the File to save to
            try{
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

            }catch (FileNotFoundException exception){

            }catch (IOException e){

            }
            //save file
            }};

        mCameraSource.takePicture(shutterCallback, myPictureCallback_JPG);
```

above code is not working, can anyone help?

Comment: Did you find answer of this?

Comment: Can you debug it? What exactly not working? Also, test mlKit on a real device, I was unable to get bytes from cameraSource on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this, there its a problem in the variable path.

Just change:

```
String path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
```

to:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath();
```

and add line `file.createNewFile();` after `new File()` like so:

```
File file = new File(path, "FitnessGirl"+".jpg");

try {
    file.createNewFile();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```